# How do I refactor a traditional synchronous loop with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to RxJS and trying to wrap my brain around how I should be writing my code. I'm trying to write a function that extends an existing http which returns an observable array of data. I'd like to then loop over the array and make an http request on each object and return the new array with the modified data.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private mapEligibilitiesToBulk(bulkWarranties: Observable<any[]>): Observable<IDevice[]> {
    const warranties: IDevice[] = [];
    bulkWarranties.subscribe((bulk: any[]) => {
      for (let warranty of bulk) {
        // Check if another device already has the information
        const foundIndex = warranties.findIndex((extended: IDevice) => {
          try {
            return warranty.device.stockKeepingId.equals(extended.part.partNumber);
          } catch (err) {
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Fetch the information if not
        if (foundIndex > -1) {
          warranty.eligibilityOptions = warranties[foundIndex];
        } else {
          this.getDevices(warranty.device.deviceId.serialNumber).subscribe((devices: IDevice[]) => {
            warranty = devices[0];
          }); // http request that returns an observable of IDevice
        }

        warranties.push(warranty);
      }
    });

    return observableOf(warranties);
  }
```

Currently, my code returns an observable array immediately, however, its empty and doesn't react the way I'd like. Any advice or recommended reading would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How often do you expect another device to already have the information to fetch? How many http request are omitted that way? What do you think would be faster (more desireable): Omit this http request reduction and instead send all http requests simultaneously (or in batches) instead of sequentially - OR - do the http request reduction and send a reduced amount of http requests sequentially?

Comment: If you really do want to iterate over a loop, check out the [generate](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/generate) rxjs function.  But I'm guessing you'd be better off looking at [groupBy](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/groupBy), perhaps grouping on `warranty.device.stockKeepingId`.  Other hints: don't subscribe within a subscribe, in fact I suspect you wouldn't want any subscribes in this function; look to create streams of data and put the operator functions to work for you instead of all this imperative code; if possible try and subscribe in only one place - build an Observable chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing a lot more about your data and what would make sense, it is impossible to give you the exact code you would need.  However, I made some assumptions and put together this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-57560707?file=index.ts) to show one possible way to approach this.  The big assumption here is that the data is groupable and what you are actually trying to achieve is making only a single http call for each unique `warranty.device.stockKeepingId`.

I offer this code as a starting point for you, in the hopes it gets you a little closer to what you are trying to achieve.  From the StackBlitz, here is the relevant method:

```
public mapEligibilitiesToBulk(bulk: Warranty[]): Observable<IDevice[]> {
  return from(bulk).pipe(
    tap(warranty => console.log('in tap - warranty is ', warranty)),
    groupBy(warranty => warranty.device.stockKeepingId),
    mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], []))),
    tap(group => console.log('in tap - group is ', group)),
    concatMap(group => this.getDevices(group[0].device.deviceId.serialNumber)),
    tap(device => console.log('in tap - got this device back from api: ', device)),
    toArray()
  )
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- Be sure to open up the console to see the results.
- I changed the first parameter to an array rather than an observable, assuming you need a complete array to start with.  Let me know if you want this to extend an existing observable, that is quite simple to achieve.
- I put in some tap()s so you can see what the code does at two of the important points.
- In the StackBlitz currently the `getDevices()` returns the same thing for every call, I did this for simplicity in mocking, not because I believe it would function that way. :)